# duda al enviar variables de dos formularios distintos

Tags: php, javascript

necesito mandar a la pagina addToCart.php la variable `$idProductoColorTalla` (del elemento que este seleccionado en el radiobutton) y el campo unidades. Ya le he dado vueltas y no se como conseguirlo. La variable `$idProductoColorTalla` es la que este junto con el radiobutton seleccionado.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    require("conexion.php");
    $idProducto=$_POST["idProducto"];
    $datos=mysqli_query($db,"select * from productos where id='$idProducto'");
    $fila =mysqli_fetch_array($datos);
    $nombreProducto=$fila["nombre"];
    $datos=mysqli_query($db,"select * from productos where nombre='$nombreProducto' and mostrar=true");
    $fila =mysqli_fetch_array($datos);
    $datos2=mysqli_query($db,"select * from productos where nombre='$nombreProducto'");
    
    echo("<image src='".$fila["imagen"]."'>");
    echo($fila["nombre"]);
    foreach($datos2 as $fila2)
    {   
        echo("<form class='myForm' action='addToCart.php' method='post'>");
        $idProductoColorTalla=$fila2["id"];                 
        echo("<input type='radio' name='color' value='".$fila2["color"]."'>".$fila2["color"]."<br>");
        //echo($fila2["talla"]."<br>");            
        echo("<input type='hidden' name='idProducto' value='".$idProductoColorTalla."'>");           
        echo("</form>");
        
    }
    echo("<form id='myForm' action='addToCart.php' method='post'>");
    echo("<input type='number' id='unidades' name='unidades' value='1'>"."<br>");        
    echo($fila["precio"]); 
    echo("<input type='submit' id='anadirCarrito' name='anadirCarrito' value='Añadir al carrito'/>");
    echo("</form>");        
    ?>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no estoy equivocado no puedes desde PHP hacer el submit de dos formularios distintos.
En este caso yo capturaría el click del submit con javascript, leería los datos necesarios y realizaría el envío del formulario a través de javascript (con los datos necesarios).

Otra posible solución sería capturar vía javascript el valor del radio button seleccionado y anexarlo a un campo oculto en el segundo formulario; de esta manera podrás enviar desde php los datos porque están todos en el mismo formulario.

Comment: la segunda opcion esta bien, pero no se como capturar el valor del radiobutton seleccionado. Ademas que no es el valor del radiobutton sino el valor del campo $idProductoColorTalla que va asociado a ese radiobutton.

Comment: Si optas por la segunda opción siempre puedes eliminar el input hidden y poner ese valor como un atributo del radio (attr-idProducto='".$idProductoColorTalla."'>"). Asi puedes capturar el elemento seleccionado y leer sus atributos

Comment: muchas gracias, me ha servido.